# Pointer output result

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and expecting the output to be `8575`, but getting `19285` as output. Can anyone help with what may be going wrong here?

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t a[4] = {85,75,95,65};
    uint16_t *p = a;
    uint16_t q = (p[0]);
    printf("%u",(unsigned int)(q));
    return 0;
}
```

//New question

```
typedef struct{
uint32 a[4];
}x;

/*declare an object of x type*/
x *block2;

uint8 b[64] = {0x01 , 0x02 , 0x03.....0x64}

Api-1
converts b into block* type by
block2 = (x*) b;
```

how would this block2 look like?

Comment: If you want to have some fun with endianness, better use hexadecimal representations, it will make it easier to observe what is going on

Comment: What header files are you including?

Comment: 85+75*256=19285. Have a look at byte ordering...

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

Comment: It is illegal to initialize a `uint16_t *` pointer with a `uint8_t *` value. These pointer types are incompatible. The behavior of your code is undefined.

Comment: It does not look like he is writing pedantic code, but rather writing a good learning exercise.

Comment: @donjuedo - Considering that undefined behavior can have **any** result, there isn't much to learn - except "never do this".

Comment: thank you for the reply. acutally i have a unique situation where from one api, i get the value in form of uint8 , but need to give it to below layer as uint16*, hence was trying out the method. do you suggest a better method?

Comment: **Always** enable compiler warnings. You should get warnings at least.

Comment: @BoPersson OTOH there is a school of thought which says it *is* educative to explain why, when you break something, it behaves in the way you see. Especially if the bug causes a side-effect unrelated to the actual problem, it is satisfying to see why it happened, and be assured that the side-effect wasn't in itself a bug...

Comment: @BoPersson gabbar has learned at least 3 things.  Byte order matters.  It is different than he thought.  And because it is undefined behavior, finding a better way to solve the problem is worthwhile.  That's real progress.

Comment: @Olaf, that is great advice.  Modern compilers generate many useful warnings, and can really save (prevent) so much debugging time.

Comment: so, how do you typecast from one pointer type to another? bcs i need to pass to api's below in uint16* , although i recieve it as  uint8*

Comment: @gabbar, it might be more direct and helpful to post the (brief) documentation of what the API gives you, and what the "below layer" is expecting.

Comment: Read want to read about the necessity of proper alignment.

Comment: @donjuedo: Do tell ;-) I normally have at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`. The latter is sometimes quite annoying, because you have to add casts here and there (after carefull inspection, of course), but has saved me quite some headaches.

Comment: thnk you donjuedo for helping me learn. pls see my edited question

Comment: @Olaf: If not playing dirty, you typically only need to cast when printing pointer values.

Comment: @gabbar, if your API defines the behavior such that it gives you `uint8`'s as shown, then the answer given by @alk can help you get there from here.  Do remember, though, that this won't be safe for compiling on just any other machine, because some use Big Endian, and your byte order will need to be re-examined.

Comment: at donjuedo , can u pls see my edited question /*bnew question*/

Comment: @alk: Not if you work on embedded systems and/or with fixed-width types. Just consider `u8var = (10 * u8var);` (-->"truncation warning"). That has nothing to do with "playing dirty, but type-safety". Actually, pointers are the lesser to be cast (I'm using gcc `-fplan9-extensions`). And printing is nothing I use normally.

Answer (score 4):

Your code behaviour is undefined (treating `uint8_t *` as `uint16_t *`).

Having said that, there are two other problems with your code, first, it seems that your machine is little endian, e.g. the least significat byte is in the lowest address (LSB), this is the case of most machines. second, you have two bytes - `85` and `75` and you expect to get `8575`, treating each byte as a power of 100 (`85 * 100 + 75 = 8575`) while bytes are powers of 256 (`85 * 256 + 75 = 21835`)

Taking those facts into consideration, we get the resulted number: `75 * 256 + 85 = 19285`

A safe way to convert such data, when the endianess of the buffer is known (in this case it is big endian) is to treat each byte separately:

```
uint8_t buff[] = {1, 2, 4, 5};
uint16_t my16;
my16 = buff[0] << 8; // same as * 256
my16 += buff[1];
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. acutally i have a unique situation where from one api, i get the value in form of uint8 , but need to give it to below layer as uint16*, hence was trying out the method. do you suggest a better method?

Comment: can you see my newly edited question and help me understand the behavoiur?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately

Comment: @gabbar: Again alignment issues.

Answer (score 3):

A uint8 goes as high as 255, so where you thought the correct result should be 85*100 + 75, it's really 75*256 + 85 = 19285, because you have byte order to reverse for your platform, too.

Answer (score 0):

[to long for a comment]

To properly align your 8bit and 16bit variables and therefore be allowed to cast from the 8bit pointer to the 16bit pointer you can use a union:

```
#include <stdint.h>

union Align_to_16bit
{
  uint8_t array_u8[4];
  uint16_t dummy; /* This takes care of 16bit alignment. */
}   


int main(void)
{
  union Align_to_16bit aligned_to_16bit = 
  {
    {85, 75, 95, 65};
  }

  uint16_t * p = (uint16_t*) &aligned_to_16bit; /* dirty, but allowed */

  ...
```

Please note, that on the green field there mostly never is a need for such ("dirty") tricks. You might however need them to get around broken specification ...

Comment: Why the cast? You just have to `... p = &aligned_to_16bit.dummy`. Note that the union is required to have an alignment suitable for all fields.

Comment: Because I am playing dirty and simply ignore the fact that its a `union` as I do *only* use the member `array_u8` which is guaranteed by the standard to start at the address of the `union` itself. @Olaf

Comment: Hmm, ... unless you prefer it dirty, you could very well use the "cleaner" way:-) Yet there is still the endianess-issue.

Comment: @Olaf:  I could, but I works this way. And it's commented ... ;-)

Comment: Please, consider this answer as sort of an "extended" comment ... - I won't refer to the endianness issue ... as others did well already. @Olaf

Comment: @Olaf: Another reason for doing it as I did "dirty" could actually be to *fix* broken code without the need to sed (touch) 10s of thousands of lines of *broken* code.

Comment: Hmm, ... I'm beginning to think I have been lucky so far not to have to make such code run, but write my own (hopefully not broken) code :-) You have my sympathy.